# Quantifier to print only three digit numbers in a Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex, quantifiers

What is the quantifier to print only three digit numbers in a string in Java regular expressions?

```
Input : 232,60,121,600,1980
Output : 232,121,600
```

Instead my output is coming as:

```
Output : 232,121,600,198
```

I am using `(\\d{3})`. What quantifier should I use in order to print only three digit numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make use of `\b` word boundary:

```
\b\d{3}\b
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jK2rG4/1)

In Java, use double slashes:

```
String pattern = "\\b\\d{3}\\b";
```

You do not need to use a capturing group round the whole regex, you can access the match via `.group()`. [See IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/rILGb2)